# Struct in Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, struct

i need to create four **Struct** in objective c

they are:

```
typedef struct FILE_TRANSFER_REQUEST_STRUCT
{
    uint8_t header[16];  // This would be MD5 of String "SymbolTalk"
    uint8_t type;        // Type of structure -> FILE_TRANSFER_REQUEST
    char    fileName[512];
    int     totalSize; //4096
    int     chunkSize; //1024
    int     numChunks; // 4
}FileTransferRequest;

typedef struct FILE_TRANSFER_RESPONSE_STRUCT
{
    uint8_t header[16];  // This would be MD5 of String "SymbolTalk"
    uint8_t type;        // Type of structure -> FILE_TRANSFER_RESPONSE
    ;
}FileTransferResponse;

typedef struct FILE_CHUNK_REQUEST_STRUCT
{
    uint8_t header[16];  // This would be MD5 of String "SymbolTalk"
    uint8_t type;        // Type of structure -> FILE_CHUNK_REQUEST

    uint8_t data[1024];
    uint8_t chunkNumber;
    uint8_t chunkSize;
}FileChunkRequest;

typedef struct FILE_CHUNK_RESPONSE_STRUCT
{
    uint8_t header[16];  // This would be MD5 of String "SymbolTalk"
    uint8_t type;        // Type of structure -> FILE_CHUNK_RESPONSE
    uint8_t chunkNumber;

}FileChunkResponse;
```

however i have no idea about Objective struct.how  can i do this.where i need to create  this struct(need to avoid class).is it write in objective c class file.can any one tell me how can i get this struct in another class..can any one help me...

Comment: Looks fine to me. What doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do this exactly the same way as you would in plain C.  Put them in one of your `.h` files (whichever one makes the most sense for what they are used for), outside of your `@interface` block.  Then they will not be part of any class.

To use them in a class, just `#import` the .h file with your struct definition in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this...

```
typedef struct FILE_CHUNK_RESPONSE_STRUCT
{
    uint8_t header[16];  // This would be MD5 of String "SymbolTalk"
    uint8_t type;        // Type of structure -> FILE_CHUNK_RESPONSE
    uint8_t chunkNumber;

}FileChunkResponse;

@class sampleViewController;

@interface sampleAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
   struct FILE_CHUNK_RESPONSE_STRUCT mystructure;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet sampleViewController *viewController;

@end
```

Objective-C is the superset of c it supports all c code... If you want to use C++ related classes change the file name to .mm instead of .m