# Using struct in Objective c to bind same type of objects

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, structure

I am new in IOS. I want to use two or three dispatch queue in my class. my class has too many properties and ivars, if i put everything in interface its looks messy. So what i thought to use `struct` So that same kind of object we can bind For example for dispatch queue

```
@interface MNHMapViewController ()
struct DispatchQueues{
    dispatch_queue_t layeringDataQueue;
    dispatch_queue_t branchDataQueue;
};

--
--
--
@end
```

I want to know is it good way to program in Objective C? If no then what i should do so that its not looks messy.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172887/use-c-struct-in-objective-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591944/struct-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 dispatch objects are managed by ARC, so your code as shown is going to get even messier. A more elegant way to handle this is to create "helper" objects, NSObject subclasses. Each can hold a logical grouping of properties, and hopefully you can refactor you big class and move relevant functionality to them. You can even have multiple types of helpers. In the end, you'd like your primary class to clearly show what it's doing operationally, and put lower level details into the helpers.